# MySQL table/query design - multiples of one item, many comments

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a site which display images, up to 30 per page.

Users can comment on the images and these comments, or at least the first few, appear under the image if there are comments.

I have a table of image references linked to a folder on my server.

e.g.

```
image_id // image id
user_id // user who added
image_url // ref to image
```

Then a separate table for all comments

```
comment_id
image_id // link to images table
comm_poster_id // id of user who posted comment
```

Now, the question is what the best way to call the information together? Ideally in one select

I can't really ajax call under each image as that would be 30 db calls per page which would kill it so whats the alternative/best method?

To clarify, in the `select` there would only ever be 1 image but there could of course be multiple comments for an image

Hope i've given enough info

**EDIT** To clarify, the question is what is the best way to collate all this information together for display - can I run one query which pulls all the images in on the page also somehow pulls the comments for images in if they exist.

As for how I would like the data to look... I don't know. This is the first time I've done anything like this so guidance needed if possible.

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you are asking. It sounds like you have 2 separate questions. Could you please indicate that, possibly with Question 1: <your question>, and then Question 2: <your other question>. For what I see as your sql question, indicate what you would like the output to be with example output data.

Comment: @MikeC. updated the question - hopefuly clearer now, thanks

Comment: what are you using, php, asp.net, other...

Comment: @MikeC. php - will update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well I'm not a php expert, but I got you started on the sql side of things. I CAN help you with php, but there are others here that are more versed in it that I am.

I started this sqlFiddle for you, go have a look and you can tinker with the query to get what you want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79ecf/1/0

From the php side, until you know how you want to display your data, it's difficult to say what your query needs to look like. I went with this for the time being:

```
select *
from images i
inner join comments c on i.image_id=c.image_id;
```

This is a VERY simple query and you will probably end up needing to add to it.

I'll assume you are using mysql as most people using php choose mysql. From my understanding there are 2 ways to connect, mysqli and pdo. PDO seems to be emerging as the preferred method, but I know nothing about it. Here are references for both. Just DO NOT USE mysql_query(), it is deprecated so don't bother learning any part of it.

```
PDO: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/apis-php-pdo-mysql.html
MYSQLI: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
```

Either of these should give enough of a tutorial to show you how to query your database and then loop through the results to get to your data. It is then up to you how you want to display it on your page.

Hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.

Good Luck!

Comment: Things tend to get more complex when you want the first `n` images and all comments for those images.  The number of comments per image varies.

Comment: Yes, agreed. The OP didn't really seem to know what data they wanted, or I simply misunderstood, so rather than guess,I was just giving them a starting point. It is likely that another answer will be what is selected, I'm just trying to help them make progress.

Comment: @MikeC. Thanks, all answers helped me point in the right direction, thanks for that - got to figure the parsing out now, thats a whole new issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest approach is to just join the two tables together, sorting first by image and sub-sorting by comment.

```
SELECT i.*, c.comment_id, c.comm_poster_id 
FROM images i LEFT JOIN comments c ON i.image_id=c.image_id
WHERE {whatever where clause selects your set of 30 images}
ORDER BY i.image_id, c.comm_poster_id
```

Use a LEFT JOIN or images without comments won't display.